# Postgres join between table and composite type

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, inner-join

Is there any way to join a Postgres table and composite type?

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.function(
        typename Type)

        RETURNS table
        LANGUAGE 'sql'
    
        
    AS $BODY$ SELECT * 
        From public.table ta
        Inner JOIN 
            typename t
        ON 
            t.Id= ta.Id AND t.Name = ta.Name
```

It always return error and I want do it because I need to send dataTable from C# project and get all item in this DataTable

Comment: Basically you want to select from a table where table values match certain fields from a composite type. Is it possible? Yes. But whether it's actually what you need to do in order to make it work with your C# constructs, I have no idea. That function is completely invalid btw, I would first read the docs on how to create a postgres function if you want to use a postgres function for this.

Comment: `RETURNS "function"` makes no sense to me. What exactly are you trying to achieve with that? If you want to return a result from a function use `returns table (...)`  or `returns setof ...`.

Comment: Note that the language name is an identifier and should not be enclosed in single quotes. This syntax is deprecated and support for it will be removed in a future release

Comment: I have fix it just I need to know if I can make any join between table and type exist as parameter in the function

Answer (score 1):

Tip: Use Lower case for column names to avoid specifying column names with Double quote OR specify using "Id" or "Name"

Postgres Unnest function can be used to convert array items or composite type items into rows. Refer https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/functions-array.html for more tables.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.function(
    typename Type)

    RETURNS table
    LANGUAGE 'sql'

    
AS $BODY$ SELECT * 
    From public.table ta
    Inner JOIN 
        unnest (typename) AS t(id,name)
    ON 
        t.id= ta.id AND t.name = ta.name
```